# Success callback not running

Tags: c#, jquery, xml

Can anyone tell me why my success callback in this jQuery isn't being called?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var queueid = $('#hidqueueid').val();
    var queuemax = $('#hidqueuemax').val();
    var queuenext = $('#hidqueuenext').val();
    var sid = $('#hidsid').val();
    var acc = $('#hidacc').val();
    var key = getCookie('account_key');

    var processNext = function() {
        var url = "functions.aspx?sid=" + sid + "&acc=" + acc + "&func=processqueue&id=" + queueid + "&next=" + queuenext + '&key=' + key;
        showProgress();
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            alert(data); // <== never happens :(
            var result = $(data).attr('result');
            if (result == 'ok') {
                queuenext = $(data).attr('next');
                if (queuenext > 0) {
                    $('#hidqueuenext').val(queuenext);
                    processNext();
                } else {
                    var newurl = 'Data.aspx?sid=' + sid + '&acc=' + acc;
                    location.href = newurl;
                }
            }
        }, function() {
            // error
            alert('Oops!');
        });
    };

    var showProgress = function() {
        var output = "<div>" + queuenext + " of " + queuemax + "</div>";
        $('#divprogress').html(output);
    };

    processNext();
});
```

The C# which returns the result is working fine and looks like this:

```
string xml = new Queue(sid, acc, queueId).ProcessItem(queueNext, key);
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Write(xml);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The XML looks fine when I debug the C#

Thanks for any help! All suggestions welcome.

Comment: What HTTP status goes over the wire?

Comment: I have no idea. How can I find out? I'll try Googling it

Comment: Use a debugging tool, such as [Fioddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)

Comment: $.post only accept success callback, no error callback (unlike the returned promise interface) Check DOC. I think your first callback is ignored (should be data object) and the second one is used as success callback

Comment: Writing the content directly might be not the best option. Consider using `JSON` as the result of an action method.

Comment: @AgentFire Very good point - I'm considering just that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post` has three initial parameters, first one is a address, second is `data`, which should be null in your case, and third is success callback.

If you need a fail callback, use `fail` method:

```
$.post('', null, null).fail(function(data) {} );
```

Also, if you feel more comfortable working with that XMLRequest object, you might want to use `complete` method:

```
$.post('/do/action', { Id: 120 }, null).fail(function(data) {
    // code
}).complete(function(data) {
    // code for complete, which is the same as success callback. 
});
```

There is also `.always()` method which is being called back always, hehe. And [others](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: The code is ok apart from the failure callback. I removed that and now it works. Thanks to all who pointed this out!

Comment: @bukko you might need to increase your 'marking as an answer rate' by the way. :)